# Facing issues with category in Magento 2.3.7

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I am able to create categories and assign products to them but the real issue comes with category pages which gives `404`, unable add them in menu and when I create custom CMS page to get products by category not getting any in that page and also unable select categories in URL rewrite section from admin panel.

Below is my category structure:

[image: Categories]

I tried some URL rewrite modules through command I am able to rewrite products URL but for category it shows `0`.

That's my issue which I was facing, please let me know if it's solvable or not, thanks.